# Conda environment is discoverable but not activateable (when activate is a bash alias)

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, environment, conda

Conda version 4.2.9, from the anaconda3 4.2.0 installation for RedHat 4.4.7-1.

```
[user@machine]$ conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
molr-py3                 /home/user/anaconda3/envs/molr-py3
root                  *  /home/user/anaconda3

[user@machine]$ source activate molr-py3
CondaEnvironmentNotFoundError: Could not find environment: molr-py3 .
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.
```

I'm not even sure what debugging steps to take in this case. I've verified that `conda` comes from the right anaconda path, etc.

I also tried `chmod -R a+rwX` on the `envs` directory and then the `anaconda3` directory, but this had no impact.

All of the different `conda-*` commands are aliased in .bashrc to point to the versions existing inside `anaconda3/bin`, so it's not using any `anaconda2` versions of `conda` stuff. Additionally, the `activate` script from `anaconda3/bin` is aliased to `activate` so it's not using the `anaconda2` `activate` script either.

Output of `conda info`

```
Current conda install:

               platform : linux-64
          conda version : 4.2.9
       conda is private : False
      conda-env version : 4.2.9
    conda-build version : 2.0.2
         python version : 3.5.2.final.0
       requests version : 2.11.1
       root environment : /home/user/anaconda3  (writable)
    default environment : /home/user/anaconda3
       envs directories : /home/user/anaconda3/envs
          package cache : /home/user/anaconda3/pkgs
           channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64/
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
            config file : None
           offline mode : False
```

**Update**

If I fully spell out the path to the `anaconda3` activate script, then it works. E.g. the following will work,

```
source /home/user/anaconda3/bin/activate molr-py3
```

Even though this is set,

```
[user@machine]$ which activate
alias activate='/home/user/anaconda3/bin/activate'
    ~/anaconda3/bin/activate
```

the following does *not* work,

```
[user@machine]$ source activate molr-py3
CondaEnvironmentNotFoundError: Could not find environment: molr-py3 .
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.
```

Comment: what's your OS? Linux? And what conda version are you using?

Comment: updated above with version info

Comment: What's the output of `conda info` (anonymized)?

Comment: Hmm, see if `/home/usr/anaconda/bin/conda ..checkenv bash molr-py3` errors?

Comment: It does not produce any output at all and does not appear to have any error.

Comment: See the update above. If I fully spell out the path to the anaconda3 activate script it works, so it looks like some problem with conda dealing with an alias?

Comment: Seems like it.  The reason I asked about the `.../bin/conda ..checkenv` is because that's the real check used by `activate` to find the different env.  So it looks like this is a problem specific to your setup/bashrc/etc.

Comment: I don't think it's specific in my case, since `activate` is just an alias. This would actually imply that it's *not* specific, but is some hard-to-define bug for conda. Are you able to reproduce this if you define `activate` as an alias in your .bashrc (or equivalent)?

Comment: Why do you have the `activate` script set as an alias, instead of adding `/home/user/anaconda/bin` to your `$PATH`?

Comment: Because I want anaconda2 settings to work by default, and this example is for an anaconda3-based conda environment. So I source a particular script that changes them over via aliases when I want to go to "python3 mode". There could be better ways, but regardless, it demonstrates a problem on the conda side.

Answer (score 3):

Make the `source` part of the alias:

```
alias activatepy3='source /home/user/anaconda3/bin/activate'
```

Now active:

```
activatepy3 molr-py3
```

Do the same for `deactivate`.

Answer (score -1):

```
export PATH=/home/user/anaconda3/envs/molr-py3:$PATH
export CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=molr-py3
export CONDA_PREFIX=/home/user/anaconda3/envs/molr-py3
/bin/bash -c "source /home/user/anaconda3/bin/activate molr-py3"
```