# Could not find conda environment

Tags: macos, terminal, anaconda, conda

I am trying to re-enter my conda environment but I am having trouble doing so as when I type `conda activate (evironment name)` or `source activate (environment name)` both return the error 'Could not find conda environment.' This is very strange as when I type `conda info --envs`, I get this:

```
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /Users/(my name)/anaconda3
                         /anaconda3/envs/(environment name)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conda environment is discoverable but not activateable (when activate is a bash alias)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746137/conda-environment-is-discoverable-but-not-activateable-when-activate-is-a-bash)

Comment: @henrywongkk no that's not the issue.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

## Names and Prefixes

For a Conda environment to have a **name** it must be installed in one of the `envs_dirs` directories (see `conda config --show envs_dirs`). Creating an environment outside of one of those forfeits its "name-ability". Instead, one must use the path (called its **prefix**) to activate it, e.g.,

```
conda activate /anaconda3/envs/my_env
```

Other commands will require one to use the `--prefix|-p` flag to specify the environment. See the documentation on "[*Specifying the location for an environment*](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#specifying-a-location-for-an-environment)".

## Adding Other Env Locations

If one plans to frequently install in a different location than the default, then there is an option to add directories to the `envs_dirs` configuration variable. In this specific case, this would be

```
conda config --append envs_dirs /anaconda3/envs
```

Note that whatever directory one specifies in this command will become the *de facto* default for future installs using the `--name|-n` flag. If one still wants to keep the standard default (`/Users/<user>/anaconda3/envs`), then they should follow the above with

```
conda config --prepend envs_dirs /Users/<user>/anaconda3/envs
```

That is, this will let one pick up the "names" of the environments installed in `/anaconda3/envs`, but calling `conda create -n foo` would still create it in `/Users/(my name)/anaconda3/envs/foo`.

For documentation, see: `conda config --describe envs_dirs`

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time I had a similar problem in `Windows` in *Visual Studio Code* terminal when I run `activate C:\...\myEnvironmentFolder` with the message `Could not find conda environment: C:...` The following command helped me:

```
source C:/myPath/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

Then running `activate C:\...\myEnvironmentFolder` gave the desired effect

If you have the problem like this in *cmd console*, then, probably, you forgot to set the path in

```
Control panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> User / System variables -> Path -> Edit -> New ->
and add
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a different method to create a virtual environment, Open CMD and type pip install virtualenvwrapper-win and hit enter this would be your step 1.
Step 2) mkvirtualenv