# Using conda activate or specifying python path in bash script?

Tags: python, linux, bash, conda, slurm

I'm running some python scripts on some Linux clusters using SGE or SLURM. I already have my conda environment set up properly using the login node. I have been writing something like

```
source ~/.bashrc
module purge #Kill all active modules
conda init bash
conda deactivate
conda deactivate
conda activate my_env

python my_script.py
```

to activate the environment properly. (I have done a lot of work to figure this out) However, I just found some example codes like

```
/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/python my_script.py
```

seems to do the same thing without the need for tedious deactivation and activation. Are they actually doing the same thing? If so, which would be the better practice?

Comment: Most of that in the script is unnecessary - `conda init` needs only get run once ever per user.

Comment: @merv They are necessary for the cluster I used. Otherwise, the environment can't be activated properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programmatic execution with an environment is usually better done through the `conda run` subcommand. E.g.,

**my_slurm_script.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash -l
conda run -n my_env python my_script.py
```

Read the `conda run --help` for details.

Comment: I tried to use this for an environment installed outside of the default envs directory and found that the -n flag can't take a path as argument. But I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58369030/could-not-find-conda-environment)

Comment: However, when I tried to test my scripts interactively using conda run, I found no console output, which is a bit annoying to me. Then I found [this issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2904). Does this mean that conda run is somewhat problematic?

Comment: @WillYang no, that’s an old issue. Please see `conda run --help`. You’ll need either (or both) of the `--live-stream` or `--no-capture-output` flags, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

When you activate an env, it <s>just</s> changes the python executable to `/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/python` instead of the system's python executable `/usr/bin/python` in layman terms.

A bertter approach will be to use conda's built in method `conda run -n env_name script.py`.

Comment: I would caution against the use of "*just*" here. It also runs activation scripts, some of which may be important for correct functionality of some modules. For example, some packages rely on compilers and Conda's compilers set things like `CC` and `CFLAGS` environment variables in their activation scripts.